# Accessing Reduce from DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

When solving transcendental equations, `Solve` frequently warns us that inverse functions are being used so that some solutions may not be found.

[image]

We also see that `Reduce` might provide a more complete solution and, indeed, simply changing `Solve` to `Reduce` provides a complete, quantified result.

[image]

Somtimes, however, this same message is produced by `DSolve`.

[image]

My guess is that `DSolve` calls `Solve` which in turn generates the message.  Is it possible, though, to access `Reduce` through `DSolve`?  For this particular equation, it would be easy enough to separate variables, `Integrate` and then apply `Reduce`.  I'm wondering about a more general solution, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could swap `Reduce` for `Solve` like this:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve}, Unprotect[Solve];Solve = Reduce; Solve[t^2 + t + 1 == 0, t]]
```

> t == -(-1)^(1/3) || t == (-1)^(2/3)

which is indeed `Reduce`'s output. `Solve`'s output would have looked like this:

```
Solve[t^2 + t + 1 == 0, t]
```

> {{t -> -(-1)^(1/3)}, {t -> (-1)^(2/3)}}

Unfortunately, this trick doesn't work for `DSolve`:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve}, Unprotect[Solve];Solve = Reduce; 
                                 DSolve[u'[t] == u[t]/(4 + u[t]^2), u[t], t]
]
```

> DSolve[Derivative[1][u][t] == u[t]/(4 + u[t]^2), u[t], t]

It clearly has an effect as it now returns unevaluated, whereas previously you got a solution. So it seems `Solve` is indeed used internally. My guess is that the results as returned from `Reduce` are not in the form `DSolve` expects and wants, so it certainly isn't the last step. I assume that internal error checking then halts execution and spits out the unresolved call.

Given that `DSolve`  doesn't seem to have options that determine the way the output is treated I don't think that what you want is possible.

Comment: Very interesting comments - thanks! I'm pretty sure you're right about the difficulties. Ultimately, I'm trying to produce `DSolve` output that is as palatable as possible for my DE students.

Comment: I think you're right; the dependence on `Solve` seems to be hard-coded. See, for instance, the definition of ``DSolve`DSolveSolve``.

Comment: It can be salvaged, somewhat. The difficulty lies in _how_ the results of `Solve` and `Reduce` differ, and likely `DSolve` relies on that distinction. The DE $u^\prime(t)=-5u(t)$ illustrates it nicely. So, replace `Solve = Reduce` with `Solve[a___]:= {ToRules@Reduce[a]}` which works fine for my example. However, it still emits a _lot_ of messages with Mark's DE, but that seems due to a number of conditions being imposed on the solutions. It may be workable, if not easily readable.

Answer (score 19):

It's interesting to see what `DSolve` is using `Solve` for. This code prints `Solve` expressions which occur during the evaluation:

(**Note** - @belisarius reminds me that `TracePrint[DSolve[u'[t] == u[t]/(4 + u[t]^2), u[t], t], Solve[__], 
  TraceInternal -> True];` would also work for this purpose)

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve},
  Unprotect[Solve];
  Solve[x___] := Block[{$guard = True},
     Print["Solve called : ", HoldForm[Solve[x]]];
     Solve[x]] /; ! TrueQ[$guard];
  DSolve[u'[t] == u[t]/(4 + u[t]^2), u[t], t]];
```

[image]

The first of these is just rearranging the original differential equation to get an expression for `u'[t]` and causes no problems. The second is an attempt to rearrange the solution, and it's here that the warning is produced. Evaluating `Reduce[4 Log[u[t]] + u[t]^2/2 == t + C[1], u[t]]` gives the result and message that rcollyer obtained.

The more general solution that `Reduce` provides can also be obtained like this:

```
SetOptions[Solve, MaxExtraConditions -> All];
DSolve[u'[t] == u[t]/(4 + u[t]^2), u[t], t]
```

[image]

Comment: Most excellent!

Comment: Nice spelunking. I didn't even think to try that. +1

Comment: By running `Trace[]` with `TraceInternal->True` you could also see that that call to `Solve[]` came in turn from ``System`Private`OldSolve[4 Log[u[t]] + u[t]^2/2 == t + C[1], {u[t]}, {}, InverseFunctions -> Automatic, MakeRules -> False, Method -> 3, Mode -> Generic, Sort -> True, VerifySolutions -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> \[Infinity]]``

Comment: @belisarius, interesting observation. Of course `Trace` would have been a far simpler way to extract the calls to `Solve`. (My excuse is that I originally had extra code in there, comparing the output of Solve and Reduce).

Answer (score 10):

As a piggy back onto [Sjoerd's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10700/52), here's a solution that will give you `Solve` like answers with the conditions still attached:

```
Block[{Solve, conds},
 Unprotect[Solve];
 Solve[e_, v_] :=
  With[{res = Reduce[e, v]},

   (* capture the conditiions via a side-effect *)
   conds = res /. Equal[var_?(MemberQ[Flatten[{v}], #] &), __] :> Sequence[];

   {
    Cases[res, 
          var_?(MemberQ[Flatten[{v}], #] &) == rhs_ :> Rule[var, rhs], 
          Infinity
   ]
  }
 ];
 Transpose[{
    DSolve[u'[t] == u[t]/(4 + u[t]^2), u[t], t][[1]], 
    List @@ LogicalExpand[conds]
 }]
]

(* 
{{u[t] -> -2*
  some obscene condition},
  ...
 }
*)
```

But, it also produces this message:

[image]

which could be removed with `Quiet`, but I left it in as I don't think it is as bad as the `Solve` one. Also, I used `Block` instead of `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` as we are completely replacing the behavior of `Solve` with something else.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a few variations of this without real success. As I said in a response to Sjoerd, it's really an attempt to make things simpler for my students so I'd really need a fairly simple solution.

Answer (score 10):

**Update (V11):** `DSolve` now calls `SetOptions[Solve,...]` internally and overrides `SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce]` (see [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148226/dsolve-with-setoptionssolve-method-reduce-behaving-differently-in-ver-11-1)).  Instead one can do the following:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve},
 Unprotect[Solve];
 Solve[eq_, v_, opts___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] :=
  Block[{$in = True, $res1, $res2},
   Solve[eq, v, Method -> Reduce, opts]
   ];
 Protect[Solve];
 DSolve[u'[t] == u[t]/(4 + u[t]^2), u, t]
 ]
```

---

**Original answer (pre-V11):**
One can access `Reduce` through `Solve` via the `Solve` option `Method -> Reduce`.  To get this through `DSolve`, we can use `SetOptions`.

```
opts = Options[Solve];
SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce];
DSolve[u'[t] == u[t]/(4 + u[t]^2), u[t], t] // FullSimplify
SetOptions[Solve, opts];

(* long messy answer that looks quite like rcollyer's and Simon Wood's,
   together with the same warning message. *)
```

It's still not suitable for undergraduates, of course.

The usual by-hand solution has the form `t = f(u)`, so an alternative is to solve the differential equation obtained by transforming the original into terms of the inverse function `t[u]`:

```
DSolve[{u'[t] == u[t]/(4 + u[t]^2)} /. {u[t] -> u, u'[t] -> 1/t'[u]}, t[u], u]
(*
  {{t[u] -> u^2/2 + C[1] + 4 Log[u]}}
*)
```

You can get back the OP's `DSolve` output with

```
Solve[First[%] /. {Rule -> Equal, t[u] -> t}, u] /. u -> u[t]
```

Comment: Seems so simple - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's worth to note: `Solve` is called by `` DSolve`DSolveSolve ``.
So the solution can be

```
Block[{DSolve`DSolveSolve = Reduce},
    DSolve[u'[t]==u[t]/(4+u[t]^2),u@t,t]
]
```