# Unexpected warning from DSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this differential equation with respect to $x$

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)^2-\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x^2} $$

With boundary condition $y(1)=2, y'(1)=-2$. Mathematica v10.0.0 was able to produce the correct solution, but with a warning that doesn't make much sense to me

> Solve::incnst: "Inconsistent or redundant transcendental equation. After reduction, the bad equation is 1-C[1] == 0"

This is my code

```
 DSolve[{y''[x] - y'[x]^2 - y'[x]/x == 1/x^2, y[1] == 2, y'[1] == -2},y[x], x]
(*{{y[x] -> 2 - Log[x] - Log[1 + Log[x]]}}*)
```

Plus, if I substitute $1/x^2$ on the RHS with $a/x^2$, the solution by `DSolve` won't include the case where $a=1$.

```
 DSolve[{y''[x] - y'[x]^2 - y'[x]/x == a/x^2}, y[x], x]
 % /. a -> 1
(*{{y[x] -> C[2] + 1/2 (2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 - a]) Log[x] - 2 Log[x^(2 Sqrt[1 - a]) + C[1]])}}*)
(*{{y[x] -> C[2] + 1/2 (-2 Log[x] - 2 Log[1 + C[1]])}}*)
```

Is this a bug or should it be expected for `DSolve`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I get the same message, and have gotten it before, on V10.2.  I think it has to do with working out the boundary conditions when the solution & ODE has branch cuts.  In this case there appears to be a singularity at `a == 1`, which needs to be approached via limits.  Or so it seems to me.

One workaround is to use `Reduce` instead of `Solve`, as I did in [Accessing Reduce from DSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10699/accessing-reduce-from-dsolve/63676#63676).  We get no warning and a slightly different form of the solution.

```
With[{opts = Options[Solve]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce],
  {sola} = 
   DSolve[{y''[x] - y'[x]^2 - y'[x]/x == a/x^2, y[1] == 2, y'[1] == -2}, y, x],
  SetOptions[Solve, opts]
  ]
 ]
(*
  {{y -> Function[{x}, 
      2 + Log[1 + (-2 + 2 Sqrt[1 - a] + a)/a] - Log[x] + 
       Sqrt[1 - a] Log[x] - Log[(-2 + 2 Sqrt[1 - a] + a)/a + x^(2 Sqrt[1 - a])]]}}
*)
```

Check at `a -> 1`:

```
Limit[y[x] /. sola, a -> 1]
% // PowerExpand
(*
  2 + (I π)/2 - Log[x] - Log[I (1 + Log[x])]
  2 - Log[x] - Log[1 + Log[x]]
*)
```

This agrees with solution with `a == 1`:

```
With[{opts = Options[Solve]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce],
  DSolve[{y''[x] - y'[x]^2 - y'[x]/x == 1/x^2, y[1] == 2, y'[1] == -2}, y[x], x],
  SetOptions[Solve, opts]
  ]
 ]
(*
  {{y[x] -> 2 - Log[x] - Log[1 + Log[x]]}}
*)
```

Note: My experience shows that this approach does not always work when one gets a `Solve::incnst` message.

Answer (score 3):

```
eqns1 = {y''[x] - y'[x]^2 - y'[x]/x == 1/x^2, y[1] == 2, y'[1] == -2};

soln1 = DSolve[eqns1, y, x][[1]] // Quiet

(*  {y -> Function[{x}, 2 - Log[x] - Log[1 + Log[x]]]}  *)
```

Verifing that `soln1` satisfies `eqns1`

```
And @@ (eqns1 /. soln1 // Simplify)

(*  True  *)
```

Using your generalization of `eqns1`

```
eqns2 = {y''[x] - y'[x]^2 - y'[x]/x == a/x^2, y[1] == 2, y'[1] == -2};

soln2 = DSolve[eqns2, y, x][[1]] // Quiet

(*  {y -> Function[{x}, 
       2 + Log[2 - 2/a + 
             (2*Sqrt[1 - a])/a] - 
         Log[x] + Sqrt[1 - a]*Log[x] - 
         Log[(-2 + 2*Sqrt[1 - a] + a)/
               a + x^(2*Sqrt[1 - a])]]}  *)
```

Verifing that `soln2` satisfies `eqns2`

```
And @@ (eqns2 /. soln2 // Simplify)

(*  True  *)
```

In the limit as `a -> 1`

```
soln21 = ReplacePart[soln2, {1, -1, -1} -> Limit[soln2[[1, -1, -1]], a -> 1]]

(*  {y -> Function[{x}, 2 + (I*Pi)/2 - 
         Log[x] - Log[I*(1 + Log[x])]]}  *)
```

Verifing that `soln21` satisfies the original `eqns1`

```
And @@ (eqns1 /. soln21 // Simplify)

(*  True  *)
```

In the domain of `x` for which `soln21` is real, `soln21` equals `soln1`

```
(y[x] /. soln1) == ((y[x] /. soln21) // PowerExpand)

(*  True  *)
```

For the results to be real

```
Reduce[{x > 0, 1 + Log[x] > 0}, x]

(*  x > 1/E  *)

Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. {soln1, soln21}],
 {x, 0, 2},
 PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Thick, AbsoluteDashing[{7, 5}]],
   AbsoluteDashing[{10, 10}]},
 Epilog -> {Gray, Dashed,
   Tooltip[Line[{{1/E, 0}, {1/E, 6}}], x == 1/E]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Bottom]]
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot that `C[1]` and `C[2]` are dependent on `a`! So the latter issue is not a bug after all.