# Trying to find the asymptote to a function

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, symbolic

I am trying to find the asymptote to a solution of a differential equation.

I solved $x'(t) = \sin(x(t) + t)$ using `NDSolve` and plotted my solution.

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[x[t] + t], x[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]

Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Solution to diff eq]

In order to find the asymptote I want to use something like the limit application method here;

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html

But I don't know how to do this since I do not have an actual expression for the function, but rather an interpolation function.

I tried substituting the variable `sol` into my limit calculations, but get an error

> General::ivar: 0.0002042857142857143` is not a valid variable.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: In this particular case, you've made a good choice as to which answer to accept. In general, however, it is a good idea to wait at least a day before accepting a solution (unless of course, it's really obvious) in order to get more (and possibly better!) answers. Questions with no accepted answers get more notice from potential answerers here, and it's in the best interest of the community to get as many good answers to a question as possible. In any case, welcome to Mathematica.SE!

Comment: Ok, thanks - I will take that on board

Comment: Incidentally, if you're sufficiently convinced the solution _has_ an asymptote (and it's linear), you can take the large-$t$ limit and plug in $x=at+b$ to get $a=\sin[(1+a)t + b]$. The only way to satisfy this with $a$ and $b$ constant (remember, you're assuming the asymptotic behavior is linear) is if $a = -1$, which gives you $b = 3\pi/2 + 2n\pi$, and you can identify $n=0$ from the initial condition. But this is not a Mathematica solution, and not something that readily generalizes to other equations, which is why I only give it as a comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With Version 10, `DSolve` can provide an explicit answer, and with some help it can even give the right answer.  `DSolve` on its own only gives some of the answer, along with a string of warning messages.  However, using `Reduce` instead of `Solve` in `DSolve`, as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63676/1063) yields the complete answer, after which the resulting constants can be set to zero and the proper solution (of two) chosen to satisfy the initial condition.  Plotting `dsol` yields the curve shown in the question.

```
opts = Options[Solve]; SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce]; 
dsol = x[t] /. FullSimplify[DSolve[x'[t] == Sin[x[t] + t], x[t], t] 
    /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0}][[2]]
SetOptions[Solve, opts]; 
(* -t + 4 ArcTan[(-2 + t + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[2 + (-2 + t) t])/t] *)
```

Then,

```
Series[dsol, {t, Infinity, 0}] // Normal//FullSimplify
(* 3 π/2 - t *)
```

**Addendum**

In response to a comment by [belisarius is forth](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius-is-forth), `x'[t]` is given by

```
solp = D[dsol, t] // FullSimplify
(* -1 + 2/(2 + (-2 + t) t) *)
```

which is positive for `t < 2` and negative thereafter.

[image]

Comment: DSolve provides the wrong solutions (and two, where there is one) due to it's usage of inverse functions, which is why I used NDSolve.

Comment: @Jacobadtr  I just noticed and fixed it.  Now I shall expand my answer a bit for clarity

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed. I didn't know about Options, so I shall read about this.

Comment: @Jacobadtr  Learning new things is a great aspect of asking and answering questions on StackExchange.  I had seen answer by Michael E2 before but had not paid serious attention.  Now, I can say that I understand it.  Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: It appears that although the answer is clear from this fine work, it was never added `Limit[solp, t -> Infinity]` is -1. :)

Answer (score 7):

#### Update

`belisarius`'s sleep-deprived brain is better than my less-sleep-deprived brain. I've fixed the solution.

#### Original post

This isn't completely automated, but it doesn't require actually solving the differential equation (except that you do to find which solution is correct).

Let's find when the second derivative is zero for all `t`:

```
diffEqn = x'[t] == Sin[x[t] + t];
eqn = Simplify[D[diffEqn, t],  x''[t] == 0]
Reduce[eqn, {x[t], x'[t]}]
(* Cos[t+x[t]] (1 + x'[t]) == 0 *)
(* (C[1] ∈ Integers && (x[t] == -(π/2) - t + 2 π C[1] || x[t] == π/2 - t + 2 π C[1])) || x'[t] == -1 *)
```

This is an infinite number of solutions, of course. We could automate this by detecting which one is closest for large `t`, but instead, we just do it by inspection, resulting in `3 π/2 - t`:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[x[t] + t], x[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[{3 \[Pi]/2 - t, Evaluate[x[t] /. sol]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm sleep deprived. Why `x'[t] > 0` ?

Comment: Thank you, it's great to see some different ways of doing things.

Comment: @belisariusisforth. It's a very special derivative that can somehow be negative but always be bigger than zero... The correct statement is actually that `x'[t] < -1`, which would be true asymptotically according to the graph. I'll fix the solution, thanks to your sleep-deprived brain.

Comment: @belisariusisforth. Wow okay, nevermind. Of course, `x'[t] = -1` asymptotically, so I wonder if my solution is just lucky. I need to think more carefully about it.

Comment: @belisariusisforth. Salvaged!

Comment: Much better now :)

Comment: @belisariusisforth. People are quick to upvote wrong answers, aren't they?

Comment: @march Been there, done that :)

Answer (score 5):

Your approach can be made to work. You can get an approximation good enough for plotting by applying `NDSolve` over to your equation over two domains, the one near zero and one far out.

```
Clear[x, xx]
x = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[x[t] + t], x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}][[1, 1, 2]];
xx = NDSolve[{xx'[t] == Sin[xx[t] + t], xx[0] == 0}, xx, {t, 100, 1000}][[1, 1, 2]]

Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]
Plot[{x[t], xx[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot1]

Or should you would prefer to plot the asymptote as the line defined by the intercepts of `xx` with the axes, you can use

```
Off[Solve::ifun]
t0 = Solve[xx[t] == 0., t][[1, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> 4.63712
> ```

```
asym[t_] = (xx[0] - xx[t0])/(0 - t0) t + xx[0]
```

> ```
> 4.63172 - 0.998836 t
> ```

```
Plot[{x[t], asym[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot2]

which is, of course, indistinguishable in a plot from `xx`.

Comment: As a small variation on this you can generate one `NDSolve` solution for the whole range, then use `FunctionInterpolation` to pull out an `InterpolatingFunction` for large `t`.

Comment: @george2079. Good idea.