# DSolve throws an error about Solve and returns unevaluated

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, warning-messages

I evaluate:

```
DSolve[{2*y[x] + y'[x]^2 + a*x^b == 0}, y[x], x]
```

> During evaluation of In[26]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> `DSolve[{a x^b + 2 y[x] + Derivative[1][y][x]^2 == 0}, y[x], x]`

Comment: Clearly, `DSolve[]` doesn't know what to do. Note that there are closed form solutions for $b=1,2,3,4$, but I don't think there are solutions for other values.

Comment: @j.M. I tested with b=3, but It also returns Out=DSolve[{a x^3 + 2 y[x] + Derivative[1][y][x]^2 == 0}, y[x], x]. What would be the closed forms solutions for b=3?

Comment: Apparently, *Mathematica* doesn't recognize that it can be solved in terms of Weierstrass $\wp$…

Comment: `Reduce` may be made accessible to `DSolve` by setting the appropriate option for `Solve`, as shown in [Michael E2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)'s answer to this question: [Accessing Reduce from DSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63676/27951). Unfortunately, however, this won't solve your underlying problem if there are no general closed-form solutions to your problem.