# Reduce in NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

Second order ode; neither the trig RHS simplifies nor is the solution obtained readily:

```
DSolve[{ Cos[SI[s]] SI''[s] == (1 - 2 Sin[SI'[s]] Cos[SI[s]]^3 - 2 

    Cos[SI[s]]^3)/(Sin[SI[s]] - Cos[SI[s]]^3 - Sin[SI[s]] Cos[SI[s]]) }, SI, s]
```

Needs Reduce due to Inverse trigonometric functions. Please suggest a remedy, Thanks.

EDIT 1:

Numerically a part works at least, I expected somewhat better result.

> ```
> smax = 0.8774;NDSolve[{   Cos[SI[s]] SI''[s] == (  1 - 2 Sin[SI'[s]] 
> Cos[SI[s]]^3 - 2 Cos[SI[s]]^3)/(Sin[SI[s]] - Cos[SI[s]]^3 - Sin[SI[s]] 
> Cos[SI[s]]), SI'[0] == -2.2, SI[0] == 1.4}, SI, {s, 0, smax}]    
> si[t_] = SI[t] /. First[%]; Plot[si[s], {s, 0, smax}]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

@bbgodfrey kindly provided the link to the answer where I learned the technique mentioned below: [Accessing Reduce from DSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63676/27951).

---

### Original answer

You can use something like the following construct to force the use of `Reduce` within `Solve` within `DSolve`. Somebody showed this or something similar on this very site before, but I couldn't find it right away. If I do find the question that prompted such an answer, then your question is likely to be a duplicate.

```
Block[{savedOptions, solutions},

  (* save whatever options Solve happens to have on your system *)
  savedOptions = Options[Solve];

  (* forces Solve to use Reduce internally *)
  SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce];

  (* attempts to solve your equation *)
  solutions =
    DSolve[
      Cos[SI[s]] SI''[s] ==
       (1 - 2 Sin[SI'[s]] Cos[SI[s]]^3 - 2 Cos[SI[s]]^3)/(Sin[SI[s]] - 
          Cos[SI[s]]^3 - Sin[SI[s]] Cos[SI[s]]),
      SI, s
    ];

  (* pops back the original set of options for Solve *)
  SetOptions[Solve, savedOptions];

  (* returns your solutions *)
  solutions
]
```

The good news is that I did not get the "use Reduce" warning any more. The bad news is that after running for more than five minutes it still hasn't completed evaluation, so I don't know if it will *ever* return a solution.

Comment: A related question is [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63676/1063).  However, `SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce]` sometimes does result in no solution being returned.

Comment: I tried using `Trace` with `TraceInternal->True` to gain some insight into intermediate results within `DSolve`.  Bad move!  Mathematica saturated my disk transfer rate in short order.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for the link! That must be the one, it's so similar to the snippet in my library. You are a braver man than I to even attempt to drink from the `Trace` fire-hydrant...