# DSolve fails on initial value problem of 1st order ODE

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I've been trying to solve this initial value problem using `DSolve[]`:

$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=1+t\space \sin(t\space y),\quad y(0)=0, \quad t=[0,2]
$$

```
ClearAll[y, t]
eq1 := {y'[t] == 1 + t *Sin[t y[t]], y[0] == 0};
DSolve[eq1, y[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

All I get is the Inverse function error.

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

The documentation suggests it has to do with the sine function but I'm not sure how to by-pass it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63676/4999

Comment: The method in the link does not happen to work in this case, which suggests that this ODE cannot be solve by `DSolve`.  You could use `NDSolve`, if a numerical solution is satisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve this equation by series  approximation, using `AsymptoticDSolveValue` if you don't need a numerical solution.

```
ClearAll[y, t]
eq1 := {y'[t] == 1 + t*Sin[t y[t]], y[0] == 0};
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[eq1, y[t], {t, 0, 10}]

(*t + t^4/4 + t^7/28 - t^8/48 + t^10/280*)

Plot[sol, {t, 0, 1}]
```