# Solving and plotting a differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I was trying to solve and plot this equation but the solution it is not clear !!!

```
f[x_] = Sqrt[( a - 2/3)/((2/3 - a + b) x^2) + g*x^(-3 (b - a))];
DSolve[{f[x[t]] == x'[t]/x[t]}, x[t], t]
FullSimplify[%]
```

`a`, `b` and `g` are constant(`a==1.3`, `b==0.7`), I have also the condition `f[x0]==f0` and `x[1]==x0`.

Comment: Parameter `g`isn't defined!

Comment: no, this is my free parameter I would like to fix it with boundary condition f[0]==f0 and x[0]==1

Comment: Ok , what is the value of `f0`? `Limit[f[x], x -> 0]` gives `Infinity`

Comment: It was my bad I was thinking about this f[x0]=f0 and x[1]=x0 and also Can we just ignore this Infinity.

Comment: It seems there are three free parameters: the constant of integration `C[1]`, `f0` and `g`, assuming `x0 == 1`) and just two conditions, the IC `x[1] == x0 == 1` and `f[x0] == f0`. The last condition determines `g` in terms of `f0`, but there's no way to determine `C[1]` *and* `f0` from the initial condition.

Comment: @FelipeDura 
That means after substituting `g` by `f0` it follows `f[x]==Sqrt[19/(2 x^2) + 1/2 (-19 + 2 f0^2) x^(9/5)]`?

Answer (score 4):

**modified: New definition of f[x] with `f[1]==f0` instead of g**

At least you might solve the inverse problem `t=T[x]` with initial conditions `0==T[1]`

```
a = 13/10;
b = 7/10;
f[x_] := Sqrt[(a - 2/3)/((2/3 - a + b) x^2) + g*x^(-3 (b - a))]/. g -> 1/2 (-19 + 2 f0^2);

T = Values@DSolve[{1/(x f[x]) == t'[x] , t[1] == 0}, t, x][[1, 1]]
```

$-\frac{10 \sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{\text{f0}^2} \sqrt{\frac{2
   \text{f0}^2+\frac{19}{x^{19/5}}-19}{2 \text{f0}^2-19}} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{9}{38},\frac{1}{2};\frac{47}{38};-\frac{19}{
   \left(2 \text{f0}^2-19\right)
   x^{19/5}}\right)-\sqrt{\frac{\text{f0}^2}{2 \text{f0}^2-19}}
   \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{9}{38},\frac{1}{2};\frac{47}{38};-\frac{19}{
   2 \text{f0}^2-19}\right) \sqrt{\frac{2 \text{f0}^2
   x^{19/5}-19 x^{19/5}+19}{x^2}}\right)}{9 \sqrt{\text{f0}^2}
   \sqrt{\frac{2 \text{f0}^2 x^{19/5}-19 x^{19/5}+19}{x^2}}}$

Plot result ( `f0=3.1`)

```
ParametricPlot[{T[x], x} /. f0 -> #, {x, 1, 25}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"t=T[x]", "x"}] &[3.1]
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW, `Values@DSolve[..args..][[1,1]]` is equivalent to `DSolveValue[..args..]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the info, good to know (thought I still have to wait for version v13).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Knowing this "magic" transformation `g->f0` I added the result , which is  similar to your tricky answer! It seems hat integrating the inverse ode `t' [x]==...` shortens the solution path.

Comment: You had already claimed solving the inverse problem (already upvoted), so I tried to work with the problem as given. The inverse method [often works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63676/4999) in first-order autonomous ODEs since $dx/dt = F(x)$ implies $t = \int dx/F(x)$. (Seeking to undo an `InverseFunction` happens on this site now and then. I probably have posted the same approach before.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Very interesting approach " to undo an InverseFunction"

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's a way to solve in terms of the free parameter `f0`.

First, I need a utility to convert a `Rule` solution in terms of `InverseFunction` to an implicit equation:

```
(* converts solution with InverseFunction[][]
 * to equation without InverseFunction *)
invFNtoImplEQ = 
  sol : {_Rule | _Equal} :> 
   With[{if = Cases[sol, HoldPattern[InverseFunction[_][_]], Infinity]},
    (Solve[sol /. Rule -> Equal, if] /. 
       HoldPattern[{{InverseFunction[f_][y_] -> x_}}] :> y == f[x]) /;
      Length@if == 1
    ];
```

Then set up, `DSolve` the system (`DSolve` is an  exact solver that appreciates exact parameters), convert solution to implicit, plug in parameters, solve initial condition, solve for `g`, and finally `Manipulate` the plot as a function of the parameter `f0`:

```
f[x_] = Sqrt[(a - 2/3)/((2/3 - a + b) x^2) + g*x^(-3 (b - a))];
paramset = {
  a -> 13/10, b -> 7/10, (* OP's given parameters, made exact *)
  t0 -> 0,    x0 -> 1,   (* IC *)
  g -> g,     f0 -> f0}; (* OP's free parameters *)

{gensol} = DSolve[{f[x[t]] == x'[t]/x[t]}, x[t], t];
gensol // InputForm // Short
(*  {x[t] -> InverseFunction[(-2*<<2>>)/(3*<<2>>) & ][<<1>>]}  *)

implsol = gensol /. invFNtoImplEQ;
implsol // InputForm // Shallow[#, 5] &
(*
t + C[1] == (-2*Power[<<2>>]*Hypergeometric2F1[<<4>>]*
    Power[<<2>>]*Power[<<2>>])/3
*)

(* Solve for the constant of integration at the IC (x0, t0}) *)
ivpsol = implsol /. First@Solve[implsol /. {x[t] -> x0, t -> t0}, C[1]];

(*" Eliminate g, replace x[t] -> x
 *  to get x vs. t with free parameter f0
 "*)
ivpsol0 = Hold[#] &@paramset /. Rule -> Set /. Hold[v_] :>
     Block[v, ivpsol /. Quiet@First@Solve[f[1] == f0, g]
      ] /. x[t] -> x;

(* Solve for vertical asymptote of x as function of t *)
va = Limit[t /. First@Solve[ivpsol0, t], x -> Infinity]
(* Solve for the domain of f0 *)
f0min = Reduce[x > 0 && f0 > 0 &&
    FunctionDomain[t /. First@Solve[ivpsol0, t], {f0, x0}]];
f0min = Simplify[MinValue[{f0, f0min}, {x0, f0}], f0min]
(*
(10 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[f0^2/(-19 + 2 f0^2)]
  Hypergeometric2F1[9/38, 1/2, 47/38, 19/(19 - 2 f0^2)])/(9 Sqrt[f0^2])
Sqrt[19/2]
*)

Manipulate[
   ContourPlot[#1,
    {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 25},
    GridLines -> {{#2}, None},
    FrameLabel -> {t, x}],
   {f0, f0min (1 + $MachineEpsilon), f0min + 0.05}
   ] &[
 ivpsol0, va
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Michael E2

Comment: @FelipeDura You're welcome.